# VLA allocation overwriting anothe VLA allocation

Tags: memory-management

I'm curious to know what happens when a second VLA allocation is done over the same variable. Say we have a piece of code that cycles over reading, allocating and processing. For instance, it reads from stdin or some input file an integer number, n, and proceeds to allocate an array, say of integers, of size n. After completing whatever processing it has to do, it will return to reading a second value for n, which may be higher, equal, or lower than the original.

My question is, since the first allocation was done using stack memory and was not freed, what happens to it when performing the second allocation?

I know how to proceed if the allocation is done using heap. Cycle through: read n; allocate the array with malloc; process the array in some way, by getting its data, and working it out; and free the array.

However, if we have something like

```
    int n;
    while (get_new_value(&n)) {
      int vector[n];
      ...
      ...
    }
```

what happens?

Did not try it, just curious about how it works from a memory usage standpoint. Does it accumulate over previous? Or does it "clean" the old?